# Combine multiple *.vbo files from multiple disks

Tags: windows, video, dvd, windows-movie-maker, vob

I have 3 different disks from my home camcorder that all contain part of my video, stored in *.vbo format. I'm trying to this video into Windows Movie Maker but I cannot do so until I can combine the video from all 3 miniDVD disks.

Any ideas as to how I can do this?

Comment: are you sure it's vbo not vob?

Comment: I meant vob, sorry! :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to "rip" the data from the discs, put the data onto 3 separate folders. then work with the files.

http://www.dvddecrypter.org.uk/

http://www.winxdvd.com/landing/free-dvd-ripper-02.htm?gclid=CKqbzbP65qUCFQrt7Qod_Fjrzw

see these for what to do with the files after you rip them

http://club.myce.com/f88/merging-multiple-vobs-into-one-vob-possible-196073/

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/Join-Merge-Combine-Multiple-VOB-Files-Into-One-Software.shtml

http://download.cnet.com/Join-VOB-Files-Tool/3000-13631_4-10718007.html

It really depends on if you really want one big VOB file on a hard drive or if you want to author a DVD and join them during the authoring process.Your question is a bit vague.

There are literally hundreds of programs to choose from, depends on what end result you want.

.